# What can cause a visual disturbance followed by a headache?

Tags: brain, tumors

Interesting story: onset of a blurred point in a field of vision which gradually enlarges such that it forms an arc in the right side of the field of vision and then after a while that blurred arc fades away.

Afterwards, the visual disturbance will go away, vision will clear, but then a severe headache (usually unilateral) gradually comes up.

No other symptoms.

What can cause a visual disturbance followed by a headache?

Comment: Please do not answer in comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're describing has been known since antiquity. What you first describe (an arc-like enlargening area of blurry vision) has been called a [scintillating scotoma](http://www.americanheadachesociety.org/assets/1/7/Issue2notes.pdf) and artists and patients alike have tried to describe it with interesting results:

[image] [image]

It is important to note that this happens in both eyes simultaneously, so that the same part of the visual field is disturbed *in both eyes*. (If it in monoccular, it is different and more concerning, and should be reported to your doctor immediately.)

The headache that follows is a migraine. For this reason, this has variously been called ocular migraine, opthalmologic migraine, visual migraine, etc.

It is never a bad idea to talk to your doctor at least once about migraines, even if they are infrequent, though a significant number of migraine sufferers don't seek medical care.

<sub>[What is an ocular migraine?](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/migraine-headache/expert-answers/ocular-migraine/faq-20058113)</sub>
<sub>[Visual Migraine](http://www.brighamandwomens.org/Departments_and_Services/neurology/services/NeuroOphthamology/VisualMigraine.aspx)</sub>
<sub>[Migraine](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMHT0024778/)</sub>
<sub>[Patterns of Diagnosis and Acute and Preventive Treatment for Migraine in the United States: Results from the American Migraine Prevalence and Prevention Study](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1526-4610.2006.00631.x/full)</sub>

Comment: Thanks very much, It is _exactly_ what I'm suffering from. Could it be dangerous? something like tumor.

Comment: Reading the sources provided should reassure you that in the majority of cases, this is a benign condition, but don't trust me: read and become informed!